# Unable to calculate road distance using Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I get two errors while running the below code:
1. Uncaught InvalidValueError: invalid argument to setPosition: [object Object] 
2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'contains' of undefined

**EDIT:** Can I use the same marker label to create multiple markers as I have done below?

Basically trying to add Markers to a set of lat-longs and calculate distance to a common point:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var mapOptions;
        var lat = [33, 34, 35, 36];
        var lon = [-84, -86, -89, -100];
        var src = [30, -90];
        var dist = [];
        var marker;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsRequest;
        var directionsRenderer;
        var markerPoints =  [{"location": new google.maps.LatLng(lat[0], lon[0])}, 
                             {"location": new google.maps.LatLng(lat[1], lon[1])},
                             {"location": new google.maps.LatLng(lat[2], lon[2])},
                             {"location": new google.maps.LatLng(lat[3], lon[3])}];

          function initialize() {
            directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.75, -84.39),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                    mapOptions);
            directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng(src[0], src[1]),
                 //icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png',
                 map: map
              });

            for(var iter = 0; iter < lat.length; iter++)
            {
                placeMarker(iter);
                getDistances(iter);
            }
          }

          function placeMarker(iter)
          {
                 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: markerPoints[iter],
                 //icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png',
                 map: map
              });
          }

          function getDistances(iter)
          {
              directionsRequest = {
                    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(src[0], src[1]),
                    destination: markerPoints[iter],
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
              };

              directionsService.route(directionsRequest, function(response, status){
                  if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                      {
                            dist.push(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance);
                      }
                  else
                      {
                        alert("Impossible");
                      }
              });
          }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
```

Comment: check this link http://christianvarga.com/2010/12/how-to-calculate-driving-distance-between-2-locations-with-google-maps-api/

Comment: @magExp Nice find.  I actually do not want to plot the directions, I just want to place the markers on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

**Issue #1 : Uncaught InvalidValueError: invalid argument to setPosition: [object Object]**

There was an issue with your markerPoints array. Instead of

```
var markerPoints =  [{"location": new google.maps.LatLng(lat[0], lon[0])}, 
                     {"location": new google.maps.LatLng(lat[1], lon[1])},
                     {"location": new google.maps.LatLng(lat[2], lon[2])},
                     {"location": new google.maps.LatLng(lat[3], lon[3])}];
```

It should be like..

```
 var markerPoints = [new google.maps.LatLng(lat[0], lon[0]),
                     new google.maps.LatLng(lat[1], lon[1]),
                     new google.maps.LatLng(lat[2], lon[2]),
                     new google.maps.LatLng(lat[3], lon[3])];
```

**Issue #2: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'contains' of undefined:**

If you are using the experimental api version(v=3.exp) for map api, then you'll get this issue. You should use any release version also. You can find details around different version by visiting [Google Map API Version information section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Great!!  I changed them both.  Now the distance information is populated but the maps still does not load.  Any ideas?

Comment: Cheers, I managed to fix it.  I did not give a zoom level in mapOptions (blunder on my part).